# Removing words which are part of another word

Tags: python, regex, list

Suppose I have a list of strings in python like -

```
lst = ['makeup brush tool', 'mak', 'flawless', 'tool', 'makeu', 'bru', 'brus', 'brush', 'makeup brush', 'cosmetic brush holder', 'elf makeup', 'key holder', 'holder', 'flaw', 'flawl', 'marinade brush', 'cosmetic', 'makeup brush cleaner', 'makeup brush holder', 'brush holder']
```

Now single words like "mak" are a part of another word "makeu" . How to remove words like "mak".
More examples - out of "bru", "brus" and "brush" -> "bru" and "brus" must be removed.

I am not able to proceed after this -

```
def remove_repeated_parts(un_corrected):
    """ Returns a corrected list """
    corrected = []
    for word in un_corrected:
        string_split = word.split()
        if len(string_split) == 1:
             # what to do from here


remove_repated_parts(lst)
```

Expected output -

```
lst = ['makeup brush tool', 'flawless', 'tool', 'makeu', 'brush', 'makeup brush', 'cosmetic brush holder', 'elf makeup', 'key holder', 'holder', 'marinade brush', 'cosmetic', 'makeup brush cleaner', 'makeup brush holder', 'brush holder']
```

Note we are considering only strings of length 1

Is there something to do with RegEx?

Comment: Can u show what your output list will contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension as follows:

```py
new_lst = [x for x in lst if not any(x in y for y in lst if (y != x and len(y.split())==1))]
print(new_lst)
```

output:

```
['makeup brush tool', 'flawless', 'tool', 'makeu', 'brush', 'makeup brush', 'cosmetic brush holder', 'elf makeup', 'key holder', 'holder', 'marinade brush', 'cosmetic', 'makeup brush cleaner', 'makeup brush holder', 'brush holder']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But is there any way to try and avoid nested loops.

Comment: @Prakket I don't think there is any, these are not nested loops, they are two separate loops. But the loop in the `any` would be stopped as soon as there is one Truth value. So this might be the fastest method out of all answers here.

Comment: Actually the expected output is a bit different now, can you go through it?

Comment: Yes it's working as needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: there is one more doubt, I have been working on that but not getting what is expected. Can you please help - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68664461/omitting-first-word-and-removing-words-which-are-part-of-another-word

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
(Without using RegEx)

```
lst = ['makeup brush tool', 'mak', 'flawless', 'tool', 'makeu', 'bru', 'brus', 'brush', 'makeup brush', 'cosmetic brush holder', 'elf makeup', 'key holder', 'holder', 'flaw', 'flawl', 'marinade brush', 'cosmetic', 'makeup brush cleaner', 'makeup brush holder', 'brush holder']
def check_list(lists,l=[]):
    for m in lists:
        for n in lists:
            if m in n:
                l.append(n)
                break
    return l
print(check_list(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution without Regex:

```
lst = ['makeup brush tool', 'mak', 'flawless', 'tool', 'makeu', 'bru', 'brus', 'brush', 'makeup brush', 'cosmetic brush holder', 'elf makeup', 'key holder', 'holder', 'flaw', 'flawl', 'marinade brush', 'cosmetic', 'makeup brush cleaner', 'makeup brush holder', 'brush holder']

testword in sorted(lst):
    for word in lst:
        if testword !=word and testword in word:
            try:
                lst.remove(testword)
            except ValueError:
                pass
print(lst)
```

### Logic:

1. First sort the list, short strings are more likely to get deleted
2. Loop with every word
3. If the word we test ("testword") is part of any other string and not itself, then delete it from the list

Comment: Thank you for the logic. The output is as expected.
But is there any way of not using nested for loops, as they are quite expensive time wise