# Omitting first word and removing words which are part of another word

Tags: python, string, list

Suppose I have a list of strings like -

```
lst = ['bed frame', 'queen bed', 'queen bedding', 'queen bed frame', 'queen bedroom', 'bedroom', 'queen b', 'queen be', 'queen bed fra', 'queen bed fr', 'bed frame queen', 'bedroom furniture', 'queen bed fram', 'queen bed f', 'queen frame', 'queen m', 'queen ma', 'bed queen', 'queen s', 'cosmoliving']
```

Here strings like 'queen be' and 'queen b' are to be converted to 'queen' i.e. removing 'b' or 'be' as they are part of 'bed' (('queen bed')). Similarly for 'queen bed frame'.

What if I have is this -

```
def xyz(uncorrected):
corrected = []
for words in uncorrected:
    string_split = words.split(' ',1)
    for keywords in uncorrected:
        string_split2 = keywords.split(' ',1)
        if string_split[1] != string_split2[1] and string_split[1] in string_split2[1]:
            joining = ' '.join(map(str, string_split2))
corrected.append(joining)
return corrected
```

But this code doesn't give the required output which is -

```
lst = ['bed frame', 'queen bed', 'queen bedding', 'queen bed frame', 'queen bedroom', 'bedroom', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen bed', 'queen bed', 'bed frame queen', 'bedroom furniture', 'queen bed', 'queen bed', 'queen frame', 'queen m', 'queen ma', 'bed queen', 'queen s', 'cosmoliving']
```

Output it gives -

```
lst = ['frame', 'queen', 'queen bedding', 'queen frame', 'queen bedroom', '', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen', 'frame queen', 'bedroom furniture', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen frame', 'queen', 'queen ma', 'queen', 'queen', '']
```

Comment: How do you know that `"bed"` is a full word?

Comment: We don't need to know that, any word which is part of bigger word must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

- First, create a new list with all the sentences split into words. (let's call it search_lst).
- you will then require a nested loop. First to iterate through your main list and second to iterate through words.
- append the word if the word is not in the search_lst.

Example:

```py
lst = ['queen bed', 'queen be', 'queen b',
       'queen bed frame', 'queen bed fr', 'queen bed fra']

lst2 = []

search_lst = [y for z in lst for y in z.split()]

for x in lst:
    temp = []
    for y in x.split():
        
        if y != x and not any(y in z for z in search_lst if y!=z):
            temp.append(y)

    lst2.append(' '.join(temp))

print(lst2)
```

output:

```py
['queen bed', 'queen', 'queen', 'queen bed frame', 'queen bed', 'queen bed']
```

Comment: Thank you! But what this is doing is, it's removing any single words from a list.
I'll edit the same in question. Please see it.

Comment: @Prakket The `bed` is part of `bedroom` and `bedding` in your new data, so it is removed. As schobaseggl asked, You should tell us how you determine a word is a full word.

Comment: No that is fine. I am saying strings of length 1 like 'cosmoliving' are removed from the list.

Comment: @Prakket remove if `y != x` condition